# Grey empty start window after update android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I decided to update my Android studio I pressed update and nothing was happend then I restart it and now  I have this window which doesn`t react to anything

[image]

Comment: try doing that again...

Comment: @AmitVaghela, i tried

Comment: What does the red exclamation mark say?

Comment: @MarkKeen, nothing